# Decorate SearchFilter on ApiPlatform

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I would like to search by roles and get only ROLE_USER so I'm looking for decorate the SearchFilter and get when the query is looking for roles=user so I can add in my `filterProperty`

But I don't enter in my SearchFilter, I don't understand why

`src/ApiPlaftorm/SearchFilter.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\ApiPlatform;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\AbstractFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Util\QueryNameGeneratorInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\NameConverter\NameConverterInterface;

class SearchFilter extends AbstractFilter
{
    private $useLike;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry, bool $useLike = false, ?RequestStack $requestStack = null, NameConverterInterface $nameConverter = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($managerRegistry, $requestStack, null,null, $nameConverter);
        $this->useLike = $useLike;
    }

    protected function filterProperty(string $property, $value, QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null)
    {
        
    }

    public function getDescription(string $resourceClass): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

`services.yaml`

```yaml
App\ApiPlatform\SearchFilter:
        decorates: 'api_platform.doctrine.orm.search_filter'
        arguments: [ '@Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry', false, '@Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack', '@Symfony\Component\Serializer\NameConverter\NameConverterInterface' ]
```